# Domain privacy protection - Do it myself

Tags: domains

When registering a domain name, there is always the option to buy privacy protection which change the information that is shown in the whois records.

Can I offer a "homemade" privacy protection service which cost less and has the information of my company instead of, lets say, the Enom privacy protection service.

It would basically be a service offered by myself instead of another company.

Is there anything on the legal side preventing me from doing this or anything else that could create trouble?

Comment: Not that I see. Just consult a lawyer to cover your bases and keep very good records. Make sure that the registration information is a real address, phone number, e-mail address, etc. Also make sure you vet your users. This si the big one! Make sure you know who you are really dealing with. GoDaddy, for example, vets everyone first before allowing a private registration. It is only immediate if you are already vetted as a previous customer. Otherwise, it can take days. In your case, you may be doing online research to vet your customer.

Comment: It's not exactly answer to your question, but it's a solution. If you want a privacy for your domains and don't want to pay extra cash. Just use NameSilo.com. Domain prices starts from $8.99 for .com and you have free privacy options.

Comment: @Kasmetski Very interesting! Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 2):

I offer 'home made' privacy to my customers.  As far as I can tell the only requirement - and I am not sure if it is a 'legal' requirement - is that the email address is legitimate and can be verified.

Since I use the businesses address and a generic (domain-privacy@host.tld) email address that I monitor, as far as I am concerned it passes the test for being valid contact details.

Now, should some federal agency come a-knocking, you can bet that I will be quick to hand over the real details.  I make this clear to people, that this service is only to prevent harvesting and attempts at con jobs.